# Count how many instance in a specific area (AS3 code)

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I've made this little game in AS3 code (AIR), where the user can drag and drop stars in different areas. 
The purpose is to put a certain number of stars in each area.

How can I do to count the number of stars the user puts in a area ?

On stage I've got : `area1`, `area2` and `area3`

and

`star1`,`star2`,... to `star10`

Here's my code so far :

function dragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            getPosition(e.target);

```
        e.target.startDrag(true);
    }



         function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
            if (e.target.name == "area1" &&
    //I think I should put something here to say area1 has been hit 4 times (hitTestObject for example ?)){
    trace("Sucess");
}
```

Any advice ?

**EDIT**

I was thinking something like that maybe :

```
         function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void{

            if (e.target && e.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName("area1"))){

        e.target.stopDrag();
        count++;

        }
            else{
            e.target.stopDrag();
        }
    }
```

So now, when I'm placing an instance in `area1`, it's adding "1". 
But how can I remove instance from `area 1` and tell it to do `count--` when it's removed from `area 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, You should try this make count-- when you drag object and count++ on droped area.

```
function dragObject(e:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    getPosition(e.target);
    e.target.startDrag(true);
    count--;
}


function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (e.target && e.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName("area1")))
    {
        e.target.stopDrag();
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        e.target.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

I am not sure but might it works.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure it will work. Admitting `count = 0` at the beginning. Then the user will grab the object and start dragging it, `count = -1`. Then the user will drop it on the object  `count = 0`. Or maybe I'm not seeing this thing right...?

Comment: Then check that if(count > 0) {count --} when you start to drag.

Comment: Do you have more objects in `area1`, `area2`, etc.. thank just stars?